# KeyError at / object_post//occuring because of python?or JSON?

Tags: python, json, django

Hello I'm getting KeyError at object_post for some reason.
I believe keyError means it's not importing data correctly, but I have no idea what's wrong with the code. If anyone has an idea I would appreciated it. My guess is my python code is wrong, but I googled around and some one says it's JSON problem. I'm not an expert in JSON(so it will be bigger prob if it's the case)...I'll post my code assuming there's something wrong with my code.

Error MEssage: KeyError at /'object_list'

Code:
views.py

## for front page

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
          voted = Vote.objects.filter(voter=self.request.user)
          posts_in_page = [post.id for post in context["object_list"]]
          voted = voted.filter(post_id__in=posts_in_page)
          voted = voted.values_list('post_id', flat=True)
            
          context.update({
            'voted' : voted,
            'latest_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at'),
            'popular_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-views'),
            'hot_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-score')[:25],
            'categories': Category.objects.all(),
          })
        return context
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = FroalaField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User, default="")
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    with_votes = PostVoteCountManager()

    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    
    objects = models.Manager()            # default manager


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title 


    # for redirecting URL so slug is always shown
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/%s/%s' % (self.id, self.slug)

    def set_rank(self):
        # Based on HN ranking algo at http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574
        SECS_IN_HOUR = float(60*60)
        GRAVITY = 1.2

        delta = now() - self.submitted_on
        item_hour_age = delta.total_seconds() // SECS_IN_HOUR
        votes = self.votes - 1
        self.rank_score = votes / pow((item_hour_age+2), GRAVITY)
        self.save()



class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s voted %s" % (self.voter.username, self.post.title)
```

Complete Error:

KeyError at /

'object_list'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.8.4
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:

'object_list'

Exception Location:     /home/younggue/Desktop/ebagu0.2/rclone/main/views.py in get_context_data, line 25
Python Executable:  /home/younggue/Desktop/ebagu0.2/env/bin/python

Edit3:
my modified view

```
class IndexListView(ListView):
  model = Post
  queryset = Post.with_votes.all()
  template_name = 'main/index.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
          voted = Vote.objects.filter(voter=self.request.user)
          posts_in_page = [post.id for post in context["object_list"]]
          voted = voted.filter(post_id__in=posts_in_page)
          voted = voted.values_list('post_id', flat=True)
            
          context.update({
            'voted' : voted,
            'latest_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at'),
            'popular_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-views'),
            'hot_posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-score')[:25],
            'categories': Category.objects.all(),
          })
```

errors occur from here

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save(commit=True)
      return IndexListView(request)
    else:
      print form.errors
  else:
    form = CategoryForm()

  return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})

I provided one argument request and the error says I provided two: TypeError at /add_category/

""__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given). 
So I googled it and people say it's from urls.py 
urls.py """

        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', IndexListView.as_view(), name='index'),
        
            #url(r'^add_post/', views.add_post, name='add_post'),
            url(r'^add_post/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-add'),
        
            url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
            url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
            url(r'^add_category/', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
            url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
        
            url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category'),
            
        ]
    
    I have IndexListView.as_view().
    why is this error happening?
```

Comment: can you post complete error trace.

Comment: your view inherits from `TemplateView` so nobody fills up the `object_list` entry in the context. You might want to inherit from `ListView` [see here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) or other [generic CBVs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: @TarunBehal I edited complete error, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Your view inherits from `TemplateView` so nobody fills up the `object_list` entry in the context.

Instead, you might want to inherit from `ListView` or other [generic CBVs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) which populate such context key

As described there:

> This template will be rendered against a context containing a variable
>   called object_list that contains all the publisher objects.

you can see it [in the code](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) for `ListView`

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
    ...

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Get the context for this view.
    """
    queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
    page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
    context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
    if page_size:
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
        context = {
            'paginator': paginator,
            'page_obj': page,
            'is_paginated': is_paginated,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    else:
        context = {
            'paginator': None,
            'page_obj': None,
            'is_paginated': False,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    if context_object_name is not None:
        context[context_object_name] = queryset
    context.update(kwargs)
    return super(MultipleObjectMixin, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

As you can see, the `get` method sets `self.object_list` to the queryset retrieved and then the `get_context_data` method uses it to update the context for the template.

On the contrary, [TemplateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/) does not perform such steps:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return self.render_to_response(context)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if 'view' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['view'] = self
    return kwargs
```

so the `object_list` key does not exist in the context dicitonary.

Of course, in case for some reason you prefer not to use `Listview` you can still perform such steps in your code, overriding the `get` and `get_context_data` methods or inheriting from the proper mixins, e.g.

```
class IndexView(TemplateResponseMixin, MultipleObjectMixin , View):
```

Given your latest edit:

in `add_category` you do

```
return IndexListView(request)
```

which makes little sense (i.e. returning an instance of a view).

I presume you are trying to redirect to the index page, so that can be achieved with

```
return redirect(reverse_lazy('index'))
```

Comment: Ah, that's why. But then it gave me another error TypeError at /add_category/  __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) which is a separate problem from the above one. I have to make a new thread for this don't I?but it's kinda related. This error is so weird because I only have one argument request and it's saying I provided two. I googled it, and it says problem occurs from url I just switched(switched to IndexListView). any idea?

Comment: I'll provide my modifed view and url

Comment: Hey, this is turning into a debugging session. Your last edit may well belong to a different question, as it would be difficult to follow later on. Was my answer correct and useful to your original question?

Comment: I agree with you, it is turning into something like that... your answer would've been perfect if add_category works as well. unfortuantely it's not working

Comment: That is exactly my point: `add_category` was not in the original question I have answered. A new question would make sense, since it is a different problem altogether. Also, it would help others in the future find and answer to the original problem as well as the ones looking for an answer to the new problem, which, as it stands now, lives under the same title.

Comment: Personally I find it very unfair to extend the question and consider answers to the original post/problem insufficient.

Comment: you know how I can fix add_category problem?